# Why Magento 2 isn't used?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

This is not a technical question but a question that i have myself.
We updated to magento2 some months ago, but we have a lots of our business concurrent reversed to magento 1.9. 
After a check on Mage Scan website https://magescan.com/stats we see only around 4% of magento users uses the Magento 2.x.x. I would like to know the reason why Magento 2 isn't used more than that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not bother with all this, those data is not an indicator at all.
do not even worry about your competitors, maybe they are silently sinking already, who cares?

from engineering point of view - this is correct way - you don't rush - usually freshly released software have lots of bugs and compatibility and expandability issues.

like many users stuck in magento 2.2.x dead branch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah that's what i got in mind, but our team got the idea that Magento 1.9 is more reliable and faster (in general) than Magento 2 with all JS and CSS dependancies. Is it true? I'm not expert yet in magento  but i work to get skill fast as i can! :)

Comment: magento 2 is not perfect but its much better and easier to design and maintain than magento 1

Comment: Having spent years working on both not sure I fully agree with that. Magento 2 has a steeper learning curve for frontend developers as introduces a number of new design patterns and frameworks.  Plus with regards to backend development there are extra steps to get extensions live. But with greater transparency over issues on git and more structured methodology to upgrades plus increased security and performance along with more stable indexing there are plenty of positives

Comment: @DominicXigen at the performance i'm not totally aggreed.. our Magento1.9 is more faster than the magento2. When we use google tools or GTMetrix to check performance, we get a lot of JS and DOM loading warning. our Magento 1.9 have not that kind of issues..

Comment: all these tools were good 5 year ago, in todays world this is irrelevant to "speed"

Comment: By performance I'm referring not only speed but scalability. For example, medium to large stores in multisite scenario magento 2 in my opinion wins. Magento 1 is perfect for micro and small businesses and will perform well if not better. Although of course there are other factors such as the number of extensions installed and the quality of code modifications.

Comment: But yeah I've lost faith with metric sites - google pagespeed etc. Run google store through google page speed and it scores low. IMHO they are setting impossible targets for modern ecommerce platforms

Comment: Thanks guys.. I think your are right. I appreciate..